An Error when Build and Push IoT Edge Solution
I follow this simple tutorial. When I get toi the part "Build and push your solution", I choose the option "Build and Push IoT Edge Solution" in the VS Code context menu and have such a result
D:\Python\IoT Edge\TestModule1>docker build  --rm -f "d:\Python\IoT Edge\TestModule1\modules\TestModule1\Dockerfile.amd64" -t regateregistry.azurecr.io/testmodule1:0.0.1-amd64 "d:\Python\IoT Edge\TestModule1\modules\TestModule1" ; if ($?) { docker push regateregistry.azurecr.io/testmodule1:0.0.1-amd64 }
ERROR: "docker buildx build" requires exactly 1 argument.
See 'docker buildx build --help'.

Usage:  docker buildx build [OPTIONS] PATH | URL | -

Start a build

and then the terminal returns to its initial state.
I'm not a specialist in Docker so studying the proposed "docker buildx build --help" doesn't clarify anything. Moreover, that long line was generated automatically, not by me.
What could be the reason for such an error?

You can use  build local source directory like this example : docker buildx build --build-context project=path/to/project/sourc from this doc or use Aliases like docker build ,docker builder build ,docker image build and docker buildx b docker build --rm -f "d:\Python\IoT Edge\TestModule1\modules\TestModule1\Dockerfile.amd64" -t regateregistry.azurecr.io/testmodule1:0.0.1-amd64 "d:\Python\IoT Edge\TestModule1\modules\TestModule1"

I tried using your command but encountered the same error. The issue primarily occurs due to the ARM64 architecture of Docker.

According to this document, the command may include flags and tags.

-f specifies the path to the Dockerfile if it’s not named Dockerfile or if it's located in a different directory.
-t names and optionally tags the image.

docker build -f ./path/to/your/custom-dockerfile -t your-image-name .

You can use the -f option in the docker buildx build command. For example, if you want to use Dockerfile.amd64 in a specific path, you can run the following command:
docker buildx build -f Dockerfile.amd64 -t python-filter


Use azure container login, then tag the Docker image with AzureContainerRegistryName.azurecr.io/imagename and push it with docker push NewIMAGE_NAME. Refer to this SO for a complete guide on building and pushing to Azure Container Registry.
